# How to sort a pivot table with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, sklearn-pandas

I just started with pandas this week.

It's a table with movie names, user id and a rating that user gave 
to the movie. Only movies viewed by the user were rated

I have a pivot table like this with one line:

```
In[1]: ratings_matrix = combine_movies_ratings.pivot_table(index='userID', columns='title', values='rating').fillna(0)

Out[1]:
 title      MovieA MovieB MovieC .... MovieN
 userID
 1           5      0        3   ....      0
```

I'm accessing the values with `ratings_matrix.loc[1].values` this return an array with all ratings `[5, 0, ...., 0]`

The movies name I access with `ratings_matrix.loc[1].columns`

I desire a outcome to put the first five movies rated by the user, since not every film in the dataset was rated.

```
['MovieA', 'MovieC', 'MovieB' ... ]
```

My attempt was:
- Sort the pivot table to show first movies with rating values because they're sorted by alphabetical order by default and in some cases the first movie is rated with 0 already that the user not rated it.

Suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try

```
(combine_movies_ratings.sort_values('rating').groupby('userID').head(5)).title
```